# Wireless Adapter is detected but not working (but, it works in Windows)

Tags: networking, wireless

I am new to Linux and have the newest Ubuntu (14) release (updated). I can't get it to detect my usb Netgear wireless adapter (i.e. I have no ability to detect wireless networks).

The adapter works fine while running windows, so I know it's not a hardware issue. furthermore, in the shell I am able to detect the adapter as a USB device, but not a network device.

This is as far as I've gotten and could really use some help. Do I just need firmware for the device? It's listed as the following when I run lsusb:

Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0846:9020 NetGear, Inc. WNA3100(v1) Wireless-N 300 [Broadcom BCM43231]

where I think Broadcom BCM43231 is the chip info.

thanks very much for your time

Comment: That device needs ndiswrapper along with Win XP drivers to work and it doesn't work well even after http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2221251&p=13010020#post13010020  I had one and gave up on it

Comment: Please see: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2264020&highlight=Wna3100

Answer (score 0):

**Hello how about that?**

1. Broadcom-USB-sticks only work with ndiswrapper and the corresponding windows driver

> sudo apt-get install ndisgtk ndiswrapper-dkms dkms linux-headers-generic build-essential

2. Download driver [media.cdn.ubuntu-de.org/forum/attachments/06/41/2612284-Broadcom_bcm43xx_USB_32_64bit_v2.tar.gz](http://media.cdn.ubuntu-de.org/forum/attachments/06/41/2612284-Broadcom_bcm43xx_USB_32_64bit_v2.tar.gz)
3. Install driver

> sudo ndiswrapper -i
>   ~/Downloads/Broadcom_bcm43xx_USB_32_64bit_v2/bcmn43xx64.inf

4. Load the driver

> sudo modprobe -v ndiswrapper sudo ndiswrapper -ma dmesg | grep ndis
>   lsmod iwconfig ndiswrapper -l # thats a small L